# Token Cleaner Java Method

Tags: java, word-count

I need a TokenCleaner method for the WordCount project that I am doing. A token is a sequence of characters surrounded by whitespace, usually a word, that needsto be "cleaned" of any punctuation and capitalization.  I have a template for it but Im not sure how to do or start it.

```
public class TokenCleaner
{
    public static void main()
    {
        String[] tokens = {"That's","empty-handed?","42","...idk...","\"quote\""};
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Original:\t"+tokens[i]);
            System.out.println("Cleaned:\t"+cleanToken(tokens[i]));
        }
    }
private static String cleanToken(String token)
    {
        /** remove leading special characters and numbers **/
        // while the token's length is greater than zero AND the first character isn't a letter
            // remove the first character from the token
        /** remove trailing special characters and numbers **/
        // while the token's length is greater than zero AND the last character isn't a letter
            // remove the last character from the token
        // return a lowercase version of the token
        /** Note: It is possible for the cleaned token to be an empty String if the given token
            consisted of only non-letter characters */
        return null; // placeholder return statement
    }
```

Can someone please help?

Thank you

Comment: What have you actually tried so far? Also, look up the replaceAll method and regex.

Comment: The template seems quite specific in its description of the task at hand.  What particular part or parts are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @KevinAnderson -  I don't know how to go about removing the special characters.  And I use while instead of a for methods for removing the first and last characters that aren't letters right? And where would i use replaceAll and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to parse every caracter , and if its equal to anything you want to delete you can delete it , and if not lowercase it , for instance :

```
private static String cleanToken(String token) {
// arraylist of new token
ArrayList<String> newtoken = new ArrayList<String>();
// arraylist of elements you wanna delete
ArrayList<String> todelete = new ArrayList<String>();
todelete.add("@"); // you can add all element u wanna delete
// parsing your token
for(int i=0 ; i < token.lentgh() ; i++ ) {
    if ( todelete.contains( token.charAt(i) ) ) {
        // you can delete it in the way you want
    }
    else {
        // lowercase it
        newtoken.add( (token.charAt(i)).toString().toLowerCase() ) ;
    }
}
// and now you can merge all elements of your newtoken list to one String
String NewToken = "";
for ( String t : newtoken ) {
     NewToken = NewToken + t ;
}
return NewToken;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the above requirement, but you can have the method like:

```
private static String cleanToken(String token)
    {
        return token.replaceAll("\\P{L}", "").toLowerCase();
    }
```

But this will remove the number and special character from all places, not only start and end of the token.

Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I am having trouble testing this.

Comment: can you let me know why?

Comment: im using repl.it and im still getting used to what it says is wrong, so i don't know why it is throwing errors at me

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how to do or start it.

You can implement this by pattern matching.  Start by reading the javadocs for `Pattern` (which implements Java regexes) and the `String.replaceAll` method.

Alternatively, you can create a new (empty) `StringBuilder`, then loop over the characters in the original string copying the characters that you want to keep into the `StringBuilder`.  When you are finished, create a `String` from the `StringBuilder`.

I am not going to give you links to the relevant javadocs.  Finding them, searching them, and reading / understanding them are skills that you need to learn.